# Why must we use natural logarithms for derivatives of $a^x$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If $3^x = 3^{x\log _3\left(3\right)}$
then the derivative of $3^x$ is
$\log_3\left(3\right) \cdot 3^x$, 
by the product and chain rules;
which is really just $3^x$.
This is not the 'right' answer though;
if you use natural logs to do this you get
$\ln\left(3\right) \cdot 3^x$
which is correct.
What is so special about $\ln$ that forces us to use it for every $a^x$ differentiation?

Comment: We don't have to to use $\ln$ to express $\left(a^x\right)'$, but it makes the formula and calculations simpler. We have $\left(a^x\right)'=\ln(a)a^x$. If we didn't use $\ln$, it would be e.g. $\left(a^x\right)'=\frac{\log_{10}(a)a^x}{\log_{10}(e)}$.

Comment: To find the derivative, you can use other method like using the original definition of "derivative", no need to stick to natural logarithm ;)

Comment: What the chain rule *actually* tells us (in your approach) is $$ \frac d{dx} [3^x]= \log_3(3) \frac d{dx}[3^x]$$ which leaves us where we started.

Comment: $3^x = (e^{\ln 3})^x = e^{x\ln 3}$

Comment: The product and chain rules don't work they way you think they do.

Answer (score 5):

$e^x$ is the only curve which is its own derivative (do a search to see why this is so). So when you look at something like $a^x$ we can determine it as follows:

$$\frac{d}{dx}3^x=\frac{d}{dx}e^{x\cdot\ln3}$$

$$=e^{x\cdot\ln3}\cdot\ln3$$

$$=3^x\cdot\ln3$$

Comment: "$e^x$ is the only curve which is its own derivative": what about $y = 0$ :)

Comment: $y=0$ is a linear combination of $y=e^x$ :p

Comment: Ah nice, got me there

Comment: But I guess you meant $y= Ce^x$

Answer (score 2):

The sentence "... then the derivative of $3^x$ is $\log_3(3) \cdot 3^x$..." is just wrong.

The derivative of $3^x$ is not $3^x$, because $3 \neq e$.

Answer (score 1):

If we say $\left(e^{x}\right)'=e^x$, then $a^x=e^{ln(a)x}$ so by the chain rule $\left(a^x\right)'=ln(a)e^{ln(a)x}=ln(a)a^x$. You have to use the natural log for the derivatives, not just the logarithm of any base because multiples of $e^x$ are the only functions that are their own derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of an exponential is obtained from the definition with

$$\left(a^x\right)'=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{a^{x+h}-a^x}h=a^x\lim_{h\to0}\frac{a^h-1}h=a^x\cdot l(a).$$

This shows that the derivative of an exponential is the same exponential, times a certain factor which only depends on the base.

It turns out that this mysterious function $l(a)$ is defined for all $a>0$, is continuous and strictly increasing, and its range is $(-\infty,\infty)$. So there must be one and only one $a$ such that $l(a)=1$. If we denote this particular $a$ as $e$, we have

$$(e^x)'=e^x$$ and this is the only base for which the relation holds.

For another base, we can write

$$a^x=(e^{\log_e(a)})^x=e^{\log_e(a)x}$$

and by the chain rule,

$$\left(a^x\right)'=\left(e^{\log_e(a)x}\right)'=\log_e(a)e^{\log_e(a)x}=\log_e(a)a^x.$$

we have established $$l(a)=\log_e(a).$$

---

To summarize, the "special thing" about the base $e$ is the "strange" property

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{e^h-1}h=1,$$ which makes the derivative of the exponential remarkably simple.

---

Further arguments allow to derive the numerical value

$$e=\frac1{0!}+\frac1{1!}+\frac1{2!}+\frac1{3!}+\frac1{4!}+\cdots\approx2.7182818284590452353602874713527\cdots$$

Answer (score 0):

The obvious application of the chain rule
is to let $f(u) = 3^u$, and $g(x) = x \log_3(3)$,
so $f'(u) = 3^u \ln 3$ and $g'(x) = \log_3(3)$.
Then
\begin{align}
 \frac{d}{dx} 3^{x\log_3(3)} &= \frac{d}{dx} f(g(x)) \\
    &= f'(g(x)) g'(x) \\
    &= \left( 3^{g(x)} \ln 3 \right) g'(x) \\
    &= \left( 3^{x \log_3(3)} \ln 3 \right) \log_3(3) \\
    &= 3^x \ln 3.
\end{align}

This is not really helpful if you do not already know how to differentiate
$3^x$, however, since we see that you have to know that derivative already
in order to correctly write out $f'(u) = 3^u \ln 3$.

More simply, $\log_3(3) = 1$, and you should not expect to get much leverage
on a problem by inserting a factor of $1$ somewhere.

The *useful* application of the chain rule to differentiate $3^x$
is to write $3^x = e^{x \ln 3}$. Then we can let $f(u) = e^u$ 
and $g(x) = x\ln 3$, so $f'(u) = e^u$, $g'(x) = \ln 3$, and
\begin{align}
 \frac{d}{dx} 3^x = \frac{d}{dx} e^{x \ln 3} &= \frac{d}{dx} f(g(x)) \\
    &= f'(g(x)) g'(x) \\
    &= \left( e^{g(x)} \right) g'(x) \\
    &= \left( e^{x \ln3} \right) \ln 3 \\
    &= 3^x \ln 3.
\end{align}

The reason it's so much more useful to write $3^x = e^{x \ln 3}$
rather than $3^x = 3^{x \log_3(3)}$ or  $3^x = 10^{x \log_{10}(3)}$
or any other variation using logarithms of different bases
is that it is (relatively) easy to find out how to differentiate $e^u$,
and we can then use the knowledge of that derivative to figure out
the derivatives of the exponential functions of other bases.

Intuitively, the reason you should expect there will be *some* 
extra factor in the derivative of $3^x$ is evident if you graph $y = e^x$
and $y = 3^x$ on the same coordinate grid. 
Both of the functions' graphs pass through the point $(0,1)$,
but $3^x$ has to grow faster to get to $(1,3)$,
compared to $e^x$ which only has to reach $(1,e)$.
Hence the slope of $3^x$ has to be steeper than that of $e^x$ over at least
some of the interval from $0$ to $1$; in fact $3^x$ has a steeper slope
than $e^x$ everywhere in that interval, including where $x=1$.
But $3^0 = e^0 = 1$, so the extra steepness of $3^x$ at $x=1$ doesn't come from 
a factor of $3^x$ in its derivative; it must come from something else.
The "something else" is the fact that $\frac{d}{dx} 3^x = k \times 3^x$
for some constant $k$, and as it turns out, $k = \ln 3$.